# BeautifulSoup import not working for vscode even while installed on my PC

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup

My current problem is that the Beautiful Soup import isn't working even though it's installed on my PC. I keep getting the error "No Module named 'bs4'". I'm currently using VS Code but I fired up the python IDLE and it wasn't working either. If anyone knows what's going on it would be a great help.

```
 1. from pip._vendor import requests
 2. from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 3.
 4. url = 'https://someonerandomwebsite'
 5. r = requests.get(url)
 6. b_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
```

---

This is my current error

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
     ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use "`pip install bs4`" to install the module "[bs4](https://pypi.org/project/bs4/)" in the currently selected Python environment:

Install:

[image]

Check:

[image]

Run:

[image]

More reference: [environment in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).

Comment: Thank for the help!

Answer (score 6):

For VS Code, check that the pip you are using (or different package installation) lines up with the selected Python interpreter.

1. "CTRL+Shift+P" then "Python: Select Interpreter" (alternatively click the very bottom left of the VS Code console)
2. In the terminal "pip -V"

Check that these paths line up. It is likely you aren't installing packages where you think that you are.

Answer (score 0):

How do you installed? what version of BeautifulSoup you have? are you in the virtualenv? you should not have this problem if you install using:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

you can also try reinstall it:

```
pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall beautifulsoup4
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue and fixed it by walking on the trail Jason showed.

Firstly, I checked the python bin file location by `which python` and obviously it showed the python in my virtual environment: `/home/.../myenv/bin/python`

Then I manually entered the same path for python interpreter in VS-Code by hitting `Ctrl+Shift+P`

The error message was gone right away.